# Simplify polyline by arcs and lines

Tags: python, topology, optimization

I work in the construction industry and have a couple of software tools specific for the field, namely AutoDesk products Revit, AutoCAD and Civil.

Presently, I have come across the problem of simplifying polyline geometry, the goal being to significantly reduce the number of segments while staying within a specified tolerance. Unfortunately, the tools that I have are limited in this respect, and to the best of my knowledge there is no function that meets the requirements.

With a bit of googling, I learned that ArcGIS has exactly what I need, a function called
[Simplify By Straight Lines And Circular Arcs](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/simplifybystraightlinesandcirculararcs.htm). Trouble is that ArcGIS is not free and I cannot buy it just for this function. I have found the function [Simplify](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=simplify#simplify) in the open-source QGIS, but it seems not to include circular arc segments.

Ideally, I need the ArcGIS function in the form of pure Python code without dependencies (I can use Python code in Dynamo for Revit, but only bare Python without external libraries like SymPy). Alternatively I need free software that I can use for the task. Can anyone advise me on how to achieve either of these goals, or tell me not to waste my time on it because it's futile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own algorithm in the end. Beginning with the starting point, I always try to create a line and an arc of maximum possible length, then take the longer of the two. The key simplification is to only use the original points to define new geometry (a line is defined by two endpoints, an arc is defined by two endpoints and any of their midpoints). That way, we get a finite number of possible objects, construct them and choose the "best" ones. It's pretty slow, but the result is very good for my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm that is most often used is [the Douglas-Peucker-Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm).

This can easily be coded in "vanilla" python. It may or may not be what you need.

Comment: Thanks, it's something. Unfortunately, I need the circular arcs as well, which is probably much more complicated.

Comment: Some search terms may be "spline fitting 2d", but all I can find are numpy and scipy implementations and not the algorithms.